# Using TextChangedEventArgs in Custom Control

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm creating a custom control for my application. This control has a text property, about which I would like change notifications.

Since it's a text property, I figured I would use the existing framework's `Windows.UI.XAML.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs` class. But I can't figure out how to new up an instance, and can't find any *useful* documentation.

Anyone ever reused this class?

**EDIT:** To be clear, this is a **CUSTOM** control...**NOT** a USERCONTROL. I don't need or want a TextBox in the control. There is a Text DependencyProperty, which changes. I am **PUBLISHING**, not subscribing. I was looking to use the built in TextChangedEventArgs class. That is the extent of my question.

Comment: Why do you want to `new` a `TextChangedEventArgs`? Isn't it enough to subscribe to the `TextChanged` event?

Comment: I think you may not be understanding me...I am publishing the event. In order to publish, I need to create EventArgs. The event is TextChanged, and I was wanting to use the TextChangedEventArgs class.

Answer (score 2):

You can't create a new `TextChangedEventArgs`, which is a special event parameter for the `TextChanged` event, but you can export the `TextChangedEventArgs` by registering a new event.

Assuming you have a TextBox in your custom control, you can register a **TextChanged** event for your custom control.

**UserControl1.xaml.cs**

```cs
public event EventHandler<TextChangedEventArgs> TextChanged;

private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TextChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
}
```

---

Of course, you can also create your own EventArgs to pass the parameters you need.

```cs
public class MyTextChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public MyTextChangedEventArgs(string text)
    {
        Text = text;
    }
}
```

**UserControl1.xaml.cs**

```cs
public event EventHandler<MyTextChangedEventArgs> TextChanged;

private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string text = (sender as TextBox).Text;
    TextChanged?.Invoke(this, new MyTextChangedEventArgs(text));
}
```

Best regards.

Comment: This is a **custom** (templated) control, **NOT** a UserControl. I am not encapsulating a built-in control; this is a control from scratch, which has a text property.

Comment: Hi, Neither `UserControl` nor `CustomControl` can create `TextChangedEventArgs` directly, but you can create your own `EventArgs` to simulate `TextChangedEventArgs`, which I also explained in the answer.